# Gridview - Summary and Percent Column

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, gridview

I am creating a simple gridview on page.
Data comes from an sql procedure.
Here is how it looks right now:

[image]

My first question is how to calculate percentage for "%" columns. Formula is quite simple:
For example in selected cell it should be 15612/238171 * 100%

I'm calculating summary of every row like so:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="sprawy" runat="server" Text='<%#Sprawy(Eval("sprawy"),1) %>' /> 
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="sumaSpraw" runat="server" Text='<%#GetSumaSpraw(1) %>' /> 
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This is my code for column in gridview

And this is code for functions:

```
    public Int32[] SumaSpraw = new Int32[4];

    public Int32 Sprawy(object arg1, int i)
    {
        var ilosc = arg1 != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(arg1) : 0;
        SumaSpraw[i - 1] += ilosc;
        return ilosc;
    }

    public Int32 GetSumaSpraw(int i)
    {
        return SumaSpraw[i - 1];
    }
```

I would like to know how to calculate value of "%" cells based on summary from one row and cell value.

My second question:
Is it possible to modify view on grid view to display data in group like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do the first part by adding 2 event listeners to gridview, onRowDataBound and onDataBound.

This is my code to this methods:

```
    protected void GridViewOnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        int i=0;
        if (sender == GridView1)
            i = 0;
        else if (sender == GridView2)
            i = 1;


        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            SumaSpraw[i] += Convert.ToInt32(((Label)e.Row.FindControl("sprawy")).Text);
            SumaAdresow[i] += Convert.ToInt32(((Label)e.Row.FindControl("adresy")).Text);
            SumaInPost[i] += Convert.ToInt32(((Label)e.Row.FindControl("inpost")).Text);
            SumaPoczta[i] += Convert.ToInt32(((Label)e.Row.FindControl("poczta")).Text);
        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("sumaSpraw")).Text = SumaSpraw[i].ToString("N0");
            ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("sumaAdresow")).Text = SumaAdresow[i].ToString("N0");
            ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("sumaInPost")).Text = SumaInPost[i].ToString("N0");
            ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("sumaPoczta")).Text = SumaPoczta[i].ToString("N0");
        }
    }

    protected void GridViewOnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (sender == GridView1)
            i = 0;
        else if (sender == GridView2)
            i = 1;

        decimal percent = 0M;

        foreach (GridViewRow row in ((GridView)sender).Rows)
        {
            percent = (Convert.ToInt32(((Label)row.FindControl("adresy")).Text) / SumaAdresow[i]) * 100;
            ((Label)row.FindControl("procentAdresow")).Text = FormatPercent(Math.Round(percent, 2));

            percent = (Convert.ToInt32(((Label)row.FindControl("inpost")).Text) / SumaInPost[i]) * 100;
            ((Label)row.FindControl("procentInPost")).Text = FormatPercent(Math.Round(percent, 2));

            percent = (Convert.ToInt32(((Label)row.FindControl("poczta")).Text) / SumaPoczta[i]) * 100;
            ((Label)row.FindControl("procentPoczta")).Text = FormatPercent(Math.Round(percent, 2));
        }
    }

    protected string FormatPercent(decimal percent)
    {
        if (percent == decimal.Truncate(percent))
        {
            return percent.ToString("N0") + "%";
        }
        else if (percent * 10 == decimal.Truncate(percent * 10))
        {
            return percent.ToString("N1") + "%";
        }
        else if (percent*100 == decimal.Truncate(percent*100))
        {
            return percent.ToString("N2") + "%";
        }
        else
            return percent.ToString("N0") + "%";
    }
```

Third method is used to format output.

But still I'm wondering about second part- how to merge only 2 cells from 2 rows (like in my second screen).

---

I've done the styling part. Maybe the code isn't looking so awesome, but it works :)

```
    public static void GridViewRowMerger(GridView gridView, int collIndex)
    {
        for (int rowIndex = gridView.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
        {
            GridViewRow currentRow = gridView.Rows[rowIndex];
            GridViewRow previousRow = gridView.Rows[rowIndex + 1];

            if (currentRow.Cells[collIndex].Text != previousRow.Cells[collIndex].Text) continue;
            if (previousRow.Cells[collIndex].RowSpan < 2)
            {
                currentRow.Cells[collIndex].RowSpan = 2;
            }
            else
                currentRow.Cells[collIndex].RowSpan = previousRow.Cells[collIndex].RowSpan + 1;
            previousRow.Cells[collIndex].Visible = false;
        }
    }

    public static void GridViewRefreshStyle(GridView gridView, int collIndex)
    {
        int rows = 0;
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < gridView.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
        {
            if (gridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[collIndex].RowSpan > 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < gridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[collIndex].RowSpan; i++)
                {
                    gridView.Rows[rowIndex + i].CssClass = rows%2 == 0
                                                               ? gridView.RowStyle.CssClass
                                                               : gridView.AlternatingRowStyle.CssClass;
                }
                rowIndex += gridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[collIndex].RowSpan - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                gridView.Rows[rowIndex].CssClass = rows%2 == 0
                                                       ? gridView.RowStyle.CssClass
                                                       : gridView.AlternatingRowStyle.CssClass;
            }
            rows++;
        }
    }
```

So after binding data do GridView I just call those 2 methods like so:

```
GridView2.DataSource = dSet.Tables[1];
GridView2.DataBind();
GridViewRowMerger(GridView2, 0);
GridViewRefreshStyle(GridView2, 0);
```